# Фильтр запросов PHP

Tags: php, фильтр

Пытаюсь сделать фильтр для анкет, для этого есть 2 кнопки: возраст (пока без переменной, просто 25) и город.

```
<a href="?<?= http_build_query(array_merge($_GET , ['age' => '25'])); ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отфильтровать 25 лет</a>

<a href="?<?= http_build_query(array_merge($_GET , ['city' => $currentcity])); ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Показать из моего города <?php echo $currentcity ?></a>
```

Обе эти кнопки корректно фильтруют по-отдельности, но если нажать сначала одну, а потом вторую, то работает только одна, хотя в урле появляются оба Get параметра (http://localhost/search.php?city=Москва&age=25)

А вот сами запросы:

```
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex='$sex' && login!='$login' && city='$currentcity' ORDER BY visit DESC LIMIT $offset, $size_page";
} else if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex='$sex' && login!='$login' && age='25' ORDER BY visit DESC LIMIT $offset, $size_page";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sex='$sex' && login!='$login' ORDER BY visit DESC LIMIT $offset, $size_page";
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно сделать, чтобы оба эти параметра фильтровались одновременно. Нажимаю на возраст фильтруется по возрасту затем нажимаю на город, фильтруется по возрасту и по городу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо оформить базовый запрос и для каждого фильтра добавлять условие. Примерно так:

```
$sqlWhere = "sex='$sex' && login!='$login'";

if (isset($_GET['city'])) 
    $sqlWhere .= " && city='$currentcity'";

if (isset($_GET['age'])) 
    $sqlWhere .= " && age='25'";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $where ORDER BY visit DESC LIMIT $offset, $size_page";
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Подскажи ещё, добрый человек, как передать переменную в age из поля input, ведь в <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отфильтровать"> нельзя вписать http_build_query array_merge , чтобы не затирались старые гет параметры в строке